# Closed subspace of Hilbert space

Tags: real-analysis

Let $H$ be a Hilbert space of infinite dimensions and $V\subset H$ is a closed subspace. Let $<,>_{H}$ denote the inner product on $H$, then its restriction to $V$ is also an inner product of $V$. Prove this $V$ with this restricted inner product is a real Hilbert space.

I think we need to reach some contradiction, but I don't know even how to start.Could someone help me with it?

Comment: What have you tried? What's the definition of an inner product? I think these things will be helpful for you to write it down

Comment: @MoonBears-C- I think that's the definition of inner product is part of definition of a Hilbert space. I tried to write down the infinite basis but don't know how to proceed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hilbert space is by definition complete under the norm induced by the inner product. Now $V$ is a closed subset of a complete metric space hence it is complete. And inner product restricted on it is an inner product so you are done.